# How to grab the values of field collection items in a template file?

Tags: theming, entities

I have a field collection `field_plaats_en_aantal` with two fields: `field_plaats` (text) and `field_aantal` (integer). I'm currently displaying this field collection in a node view as an unordered list:

[image: Unordered list]

I'd now like to theme the field collection a bit in order to get something like this instead:

[image: New display]

It seems fairly easy, but I can't find a way to achieve this. At first, I tried to work with a template file `views-view-field--field-plaats-en-aantal.tpl.php`, but I don't know how to grab the values of the field collection items there. Is this a good way to work on? If yes, how can I get the needed values?

Afterwards, I read some things on the internet about templates for the field collection items themselves and tried using two templates `field-collection-item--field-plaats.tpl.php` and `field-collection-item--field-aantal.tpl.php`, because that seemed an easier solution to me. However, those files aren't scanned and therefore don't affect the theming of the fields. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can do literally all of that with CSS...

Comment: @Clive: Yes, I've achieved what I want by using the default classes. Thanks for the motivating hint. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was making things too complicated: the theming can be achieved with CSS by using the default classes of the field collection. Hopefully, my code underneath can be helpful for others too.

```
.item-list li {
  list-style: none;
}

.field-name-field-plaats:before {
  content: "@ ";
}

.field-name-field-plaats {
  display: inline;
}

.field-items {
  display: inline-block;
}

.field-name-field-aantal:before {
  content: " (";
}

.field-name-field-aantal:after {
  content: "x)";
}

.field-name-field-aantal {
  display: inline;
}
```